# Mailto link in aruba webmail client

Tags: html, email, mailto, webmail, aruba

I have a website that has a contact us form, when the user clicks on send i receive an html email, i wanted to add to this email a button for replying to this email with the subject and the body pre filled. I've tried this but aruba open the composition form and populates only the subject and not the body:

```
<a href="mailto:email@example.com?subject=hello&body=test">Answer</a>
```

to open the composition form with the subject and the body prefilled.